# ¿Como puedo enviar un parametro dentro de el cuerpo de un json?

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente cadena json:

```json
{
"test":"", 
"test": "numeroDocumento",
"test": "test"
}
```

Comment: El operador `%` sólo funciona con cadenas, por lo que no puedes emplearlo con diccionarios como `request_servicio`. Pero es que no te hace falta, basta con que cambies el elemento que necesitas: `request_servicio['tsec'] = access_token`.

Comment: Puedes asignarlo directamente al crear tu diccionario: `request_servicio ={'tsec': access_token, ...}`

Comment: Lo asigne directamente y funciono sin problemas. Muchas Gracias !! @solarc

Answer (score 1):

```
request_servicio ={'tsec':'%s', 'numeroDocumento': 'numeroDocumento','tipoDocumento': 'tipoDocumento'} %(tsec)
```

esta linea esta mal.
request _servicio es un diccionario y no puedes "formatear" un diccionario que es lo que haces con %s

```
request_servicio ={'tsec': tsec, 'numeroDocumento': 'numeroDocumento','tipoDocumento': 'tipoDocumento'}
```

si quieres asegurarte de que el valor es un string puedes declararlo

```
request_servicio ={'tsec': str(tsec), 'numeroDocumento': 'numeroDocumento','tipoDocumento': 'tipoDocumento'}
```